# Padding missing in the table of the tag synonyms page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-synonyms

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img205/3910/tagsk.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img205/3910/tagsk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks much nicer now :)